# Using bootstrap to align dropdown-menu to middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap I am trying to get this [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYSQe.png) menu to appear as a small box in the middle of the page. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS8Gv.png).

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button 
  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
  type="button" 
  id="dropdownMenu1" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" 
  aria-expanded="true">
    List
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: 0;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">First</a></li>
    <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Third</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the standard style of dropdown-menu:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  width: 200px;
  text-align:center !important;
  float: none !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid center">
  <div class="col-md-5">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        List
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: 0;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">First</a>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Second</a>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Third</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi sorry maybe I wasn't clear, I want it to look something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/OvVAMMk.png).

Comment: @Jermain189 sorry, could you check if is this what do you try to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, in your snippet it is how I want it. However when I try to add it to my code it does not work. Do i have to edit the css with .center and .dropdown-menu?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how your layout is done, but yes you could try to override the standard class style, with the clause !important, btw try to edit your question with more markup, so I can check if there are other problems

Answer (score -1):

How about using `<select size="1"><option>...</option></select>`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question